# Laravel Eloquent to php

Tags: laravel-5.6

How to make delete function in laravel model, usually when in blade we use :

```
<form action="{{ action('ItemNameController@destroy', $ItemName->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-style" href="{{ $ItemName->id }}" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete This Item? #{{ $ItemName->inc }} ')">
</form>
```

So how to write that code when we write it in controller, because in controller cannot to write eloquent or cannot to process (.blade.php)

**Example in Controller:**

```
foreach ($i as $value) {
            echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
            echo "<th><input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-style' href=' value='Delete' value='Delete' style='font-size: 10px'></th>";
            echo "</form>";
           }
```

Comment: Try explain better what you want to do. I dont know what you thinking about

Comment: i have changed it @CaShiS

Comment: can you help me sir please @Salama96

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a this by:

```
<form action="{{ action('ItemNameController@destroy', $ItemName->id) }}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-style" href="{{ $ItemName->id }}" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete This Item? #{{ $ItemName->inc }} ')">
</form>
```

Where in your controller you would handle the delete method. If you were using an ajax request you could send a delete request to the server.

Your route something like be:

```
Route::post('/itemname/{ItemName}/delete', 'ItemNameController@destroy');
```

To stop it being confused with:

```
Route::post('itemname/{ItemName}', 'ItemNameController@update);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to change code above (eloquent) into php native, because i want to write it in controller

Comment: I'm not really sure why since you're using laravel? Why wouldn't you utilise all the helpers Laravel offers? You can simple just call `$model->delete();` in your destroy function.